# Android Drag / Animation

Tags: java, android

I want to make a page where you can drag an image (and play a little animation)

so i'm doing something (and i think it's not ideal - so i need your help):

my code:

```
ButtonIMG = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ButtonIMG );
Canvas c = null;
while (true) {
    if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        continue;
    }
    if (gifCounter<10){
        animataion = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.animataion1);
        gifCounter++;
    }
    if (gifCounter<20 && gifCounter>=10){
        animataion = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.animataion2);
        gifCounter++;
    }
    if (gifCounter<30 && gifCounter>=20){
        animataion = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.animataion3);
        gifCounter++;
    }
    if (gifCounter>=30){
        gifCounter=0;
    }
    c = holder.lockCanvas();
    c.drawARGB(255, 220, 220, 220);
    c.drawBitmap(ButtonIMG, x, y, null);
    c.drawBitmap(animataion, 100, 100, null);
}
```

.
.
.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
    switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i think it's not ideal` what are you trying to say? Errors? No drag? no amination?

Comment: @vini - it works fine, but i think this loop that is painting the screen all the time maybe waste of resources. can i just add an img in x,y pos - and change it's place when i call a function?

Comment: is your image painted all over the canvas where ever you drag? Are you clearing the canvas for drag event.

Comment: the image is a small part of the canvas, and every loop it draws c.drawARGB(255, 220, 220, 220) - so it's clearing the canvas...